# Square-integrable functions tend to zero at $\pm \infty$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

Is it true that all differentiable square-integrable functions tend to zero at $\pm \infty$? If that is not true could you give a counterexample?

Comment: Only if the limit exists. In which case the proof is trivial.

Comment: If $\lim_{x\to \infty }$ exist, then yes it's true. Otherwise, you can have that $f\in L^p$ (where $p\geq 1$) and $\limsup_{x\to \infty }f(x)=+\infty $. But it's nevertheless true that $\liminf_{x\to \infty }f=0$.

Comment: $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\exp\left[-n^4(x-n)^2\right]\in L^2$$ but for any $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$ we have $f(n)\geq 1$.

Comment: Is this function differentiable?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f =\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} nI_{(n,n+\frac 1 {n^{4}})}$. Can you see that this is a counterexample?