# Square-integrable eigenfunctions of the Schrödinger operator decay $\pm \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, hilbert-spaces, eigenfunctions

Why is it necessary for an eigenfunction of $H=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+u(x)$ that is square-integrable that it tends to zero at $\pm \infty$?

Comment: What is the tail of integral? Could you give a detailed proof?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297567/square-integrable-functions-tend-to-zero-at-pm-infty

Comment: What is $u$? $\ $

Comment: @cmk: $u$ is usually a potential function of some kind, like potential energy.

Comment: @AdrianKeister You're right, of course, but I was encouraging them to add more context to their problem, like their assumptions on $u$. Otherwise, they're risking having their question closed.

Comment: @cmk: Well, perhaps; on the other hand, mentioning that $H=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+u$ is a Schrodinger operator could be interpreted as giving that information.

Comment: @AdrianKeister I don't disagree with you, but I'd say that if someone is looking at the problem statement and sees "show $L^2$ eigenfunctions of $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+u$ vanish at infinity," they might like to know what assumptions are present on $u$ before providing a rigorous argument. FYI, I agree with your physical interpretation of the problem and +1'd.

Comment: @cmk: Sure, that's a good point. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

Mainly because of the probability interpretation. If $\psi$ is an eigenfunction of the Schrodinger equation, then the statistical interpretation says that $\int_a^b|\psi(x)|^2\,dx$ gives the probability of finding the particle between $a$ and $b$. By the rules of probability, we must have $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\psi(x)|^2\,dx=1<\infty.$ This certainly cannot happen unless the function itself decays to zero.